# TableView JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Как в TableView закрасить определенные ячейки. Как закрасить нужные строки знаю, а с ячейками не получается. Если не сложно, то с примером кода. Спасибо

Comment: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/ Вот то что вам нужно

Comment: В принципе подходит, но не знаю как быть с тем: 1) когда данная строка находится в фокусе, нодо чтобы новый стиль ячейки не применялся (setStyle(""););  2) мне надо сравнивать другое поле объекта, при закрашивании ячейки, а в данном случае получается сравнивать, только то поле, ячейку которого выделяем цветом.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе подходит, но не знаю как быть с тем: 1) когда данная строка находится в фокусе, нодо чтобы новый стиль ячейки не применялся (setStyle("");); 2) надо сравнивать другое поле объекта, при закрашивании ячейки, а в данном случае получается сравнивать, только то поле, ячейку которого выделяем цветом.

```
tcName.setCellFactory(column -> {
return new TableCell<Employee, String>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            setText(item.equals("..."));

            if () {
                setTextFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
            } else {
                setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    }
};
});
```